# Load Data in Divs on another page based on dropdown form selections

Tags: javascript, php, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a form that has 2 dropdown menu's:

```
<form id="form1">
<select name="sweets" id="sweets">
  <option value="Cake">Cake</option>
  <option value="Pie">Pie</option>
</select>

<select name="candy" id="candy">
  <option value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
  <option value="Gum">Gum</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Say that I select option 'Cake' in first dropdown and option 'Gum' in second dropdown and hit submit, I would like to load 2 divs on the next page i.e.

```
        <div id="cake">some data</div> and <div id="gum">some data</div>
```

Since 'Pie' and 'Chocolate' weren't selected, I would not want them to load any related data on the next page.

Similarly, if I choose 'Cake' and 'Chocolate', the related divs should open up on the next page.

I'm trying to Load Data on another page based on multiple form selections. I'm completely zonked and don't have a clue of how to pass data to another page based on these dropdown selections. I have tried a bit of javascript as well as php but didn't come close to any solution.

Can someone please help! Or point me out in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: If you're using PHP, that would seem to be the easiest solution. BTW your form is missing both the action and method params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a bunch of different methods, here is one using `switch`

form.php

```
<form id="form1" action="display.php" method="post">
<select name="sweets" id="sweets">
  <option value="Cake">Cake</option>
  <option value="Pie">Pie</option>
</select>

<select name="candy" id="candy">
  <option value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
  <option value="Gum">Gum</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

display.php

```
switch($_POST['sweets']){
    case 'Cake':
          echo '<div id="cake">some data</div>';
          break;
    case 'Pie':
          echo '<div id="pie">some data</div>';
          break;
    default:
          break;
}

switch($_POST['candy']){
    case 'Chocolate':
          echo '<div id="chocolate">some data</div>';
          break;
    case 'Gum':
          echo '<div id="gum">some data</div>';
          break;
    default:
          break;
}
```

EDIT: When using checkboxes

```
<input name="candy[]" type="checkbox" value="Chocolate">Chocolate
<input name="candy[]" type="checkbox" value="Gum">Gum

foreach($_POST['candy'] as $candy){
    switch($candy){
        case 'Chocolate':
          echo '<div id="chocolate">some data</div>';
          break;
        case 'Gum':
          echo '<div id="gum">some data</div>';
          break;
        default:
          break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Genius buddy! Just what I needed.Why didn't I come across such simple code anywhere else. This allows me to tweak according to what i need. Thanks Chris!

Comment: I've come across a slight problem. I've used the same above code but instead of using a dropdownmenu, I'm using checkboxes. The code works fine with a dropdownmenu if you do not select any option. But if a checkbox is not selected, I get an **Undefined index: candy in C:\wamp\www\the_form\display.php on line 38**. Do i need to add some code to the above? The form code is: '<input name="candy" type="checkbox" value="Gum">Gum <input name="chocolate" type="checkbox" value="Chocolate">Chocolate'

Comment: I figured it out. I used `isset`. I replaced `switch($_POST['candy'])` with `switch (isset($_POST['chocolate']) ? $_POST['chocolate'] : null)` This way, the first time you run the page, the _chocolate_ index doesn't exist because it hasn't been sent over from the form. When you submit the form it will then exist, and it won't complain about it. Hoorah!